# Split string into three columns in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data in BigQuery with the following schema:

```sql
select x from unnest(['a - b - c', 'd - e - f']) as x
```

I would like to obtain 3 columns, `x1`, `x2` and `x3` with the following values in each column:

```
x1,x2,x3
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

How can I do that in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()`:

```
select x,
       split(x, ' - ')[safe_ordinal(1)] as x1,
       split(x, ' - ')[safe_ordinal(2)] as x2,
       split(x, ' - ')[safe_ordinal(3)] as x3
from unnest(['a - b - c', 'd - e - f']) as x
```

Answer (score 1):

Another "trick" is to use [PIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) operator as in example below

```
select * except(x) from (
  select * from data, unnest(split(x, ' - ')) val with offset
)
pivot(max(val) for offset in (0 as x1, 1 as x2, 2 as x3))
```

If applied to sample data in your question

```
with data as (select x from unnest(['a - b - c', 'd - e - f']) as x)
```

the output is

[image]